# Get all scope variables from query parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angularjs-scope

As the title says, what I want to do is grab all variables from the URL and place them in the scope variables.

Essentially, I'll have a URL like this (format may be changed)

```
http://example.com?opt.val=true&eg=foobar
```

I also have my controller code which looks something like:

```
m.controller('maps', function ($scope) {
    $scope.opts = {
        val: false,
        lav: false
    };
    $scope.eg = "Hello, World!";
});
```

---

Essentially, what I want to do is to grab this part: `opt.val=true&eg=foobar` and set the controller variables to those values so I'll end up with my variables as:

```
$scope.opt.val = true;
$scope.eg      = "foobar";
$scope.lav     = false;
```

---

Is there an "angular" or better way to do this rather than evaling / parsing the url, then just looping and dumping it in the scope? This seems like a very "hacky" way.

---

If this isn't clear enough, I'll be happy to provide more clarification

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, for starters, you can simply grab the values using the `$location` service

```
var search = $location.search();
// should look like
// {
//     "opt.val": "true",
//     "eg": "foobar"
// }
```

Next, you can use the `$parse` service to assign the values to your `$scope`

```
angular.forEach(search, function(val, key) {
    $parse(key).assign($scope, val);
});
```

Keep in mind that every value in `$location.search()` is a string, including `"true"` and `"false"` so you may need some extra logic to handle those if you want Boolean values. Maybe something like this

```
angular.forEach(search, function(val, key) {
    var evald = $scope.$eval(val);
    if (evald !== undefined) {
        val = evald;
    }
    $parse(key).assign($scope, val);
});
```

Plunker demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/xOnDdWUW8PgsMFgmXr0r?p=preview

Comment: Do you really need the line with `$parse` there, or `$scope[key] = val;` would be good enough ?

Comment: @TMG that would set `$scope['opt.val']`, not `$scope.opt.val`

Comment: Cool solution pretty much want I want but is there an "angular" way to generate the query parameters from the $scope variables or should I just loop & join

Comment: @Vɪʜᴀɴ I'm not sure what you mean but you can use `$location.search()` as a setter. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search

Comment: @Phil when I use $location.search to set the query parameter, it throws an error when the $eval tries to parse it. Could this be because it doesn't have quotes?

Comment: @Phil to be specific, it goes [here]https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B²%5D&p2=²(x%5Bt%3Dxn%2F2%5Dc%2Bxv%5Bt%5Dc)%2F2). The problem seems to arise then unicode characters are entered. I think I might have to wrap it in a string

Answer (score 5):

There are some ways you can do that:

## #1 Using $StateParams

If you are using [URLRouting](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) of angular, you can use $stateParams which returns exactly what you want. All you have to do, is define your parameters in your Router. Example:

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts.detail', {
    url: "/contacts?myParam&myParam2",
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams) {
        // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
        expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
    }
})
```

This defines your route contacts receiving **myParam** and **myParam2**. After this, you can use **$stateParamsService** to parse this parameters in your controller very easy:

```
controller: function($stateParams){
  $stateParams.myParam //*** Exists! ***//
 }
```

## #2 Using $location

If you aren't using routes, and want more low-level service, you can inject [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) in your controller and service, and parse the querys, eg:

```
var paramValue = $location.search().myParam;
```

But it is necessary to enable html5mode first, and it will work

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You don't need HTML5 mode to use `$location.search()`

Answer (score 4):

Angular way would be. Just inject $routeParams in your controller.

See example below

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
//
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
```

See more details here [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Comment: This isn't so much the *"Angular way"* as it is the *"ngRoute way"*

Answer (score 1):

[url.js](https://github.com/kevincox/url.js) may be useful to you. Example:

```
url.parse("http://example.com?opt.val=true&eg=foobar").get.eg === "foobar"
```